# Scoring a Scrabble Word

Tags: c#, object-oriented, game, interview-questions, console

I was asked before an interview to create a console application that will work out the score of a word for the board game scrabble. It worked fine but the feedback I received said:

"there were no comments at all, some strange logic and uses exceptions to handle bad input.
In summary the Developers reviewing this felt this was not bad, though seemed a little rushed or inexperienced."

In regards to the comments I found that many places recommend naming variable and method names well enough to not need comments?

Also I was wondering what they meant by the weird logic.

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Scrabble
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Scrabble Calculator!");
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a word:");

                Word NewScrabbleWord = new Word(Console.ReadLine());


                Console.WriteLine("Your score for this word is: {0}\n", NewScrabbleWord.Score);

            }
            catch (Exception all)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(all.Message + "\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit q to quit or hit any other key to continue.");
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Q);
    }

}
}
```

Word.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Scrabble
{
    class Word
    {
        public string Value { get; private set; }
        public char[] Letters
        {
            get
            {
                if (!Value.Contains(" "))
                    return Regex.Replace(Value.ToLower(), "[^a-z]+", "").ToArray();
                else
                    throw new Exception("Enter only one word");
            }
        }
        public int Length
        {
            get
            {
                if (Letters.Any())
                    return Letters.Count();
                else
                    throw new Exception("You never entered anything");
            }
        }
        public int Score
        {
            get
            {
                return CalculateScore();
            }
        }

        public Word(string Word)
        {
            this.Value = Word;
        }

        private int CalculateScore()
        {
            int CurrentScore = 0;
            CurrentScore += GetLetterPoints();

            if (BonusPoints()) CurrentScore += 3;

            CurrentScore *= GetMultiplier();

            return CurrentScore;
        }

        private int GetLetterPoints()
        {
            int score = 0;
            foreach (char letter in this.Letters)
            {
                switch (letter)
                {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'o':
                    case 's':
                        score += 1;
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                    case 'f':
                    case 'g':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'l':
                    case 'r':
                    case 't':
                    case 'u':
                        score += 2;
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                    case 'h':
                    case 'k':
                    case 'm':
                    case 'n':
                        score += 3;
                        break;
                    case 'j':
                    case 'p':
                    case 'w':
                    case 'y':
                        score += 5;
                        break;
                    case 'q':
                        score += 7;
                        break;
                    case 'v':
                    case 'z':
                        score += 8;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return score;
        }

        private bool BonusPoints()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Letters.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                    if (Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
                        return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        private int GetMultiplier()
        {
            if (this.Length <= 4)
                return 1;
            else if (this.Length <= 6)
                return 2;
            else if (this.Length <= 9)
                return 3;
            else
                return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not relevant to the code itself, but...I don't think you're using the official Scrabble rules. (Actually it would make sense that you were not given the "correct" rules, because they don't want you to just copy and paste someone else's Scrabble code!)  But you might want to clarify the task a little, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I like how they said it seemed rushed.  Did you do this on site during the interview or post interview?

Comment: Thanks for all the reply's guys. I did this pre Interview. It was a simple task so I assumed a simple program would be good enough.

Comment: for goodness sake **USE AN ARRAY** for the 26 score values.  Good grief.

Comment: Yes well I was going to use a dictionary and have many index's all link to the same number but I couldn't figure out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whoa!

Don't do this:

> ```
>     private bool BonusPoints()
>     {
>         for (int i = 0; i < this.Letters.Count(); i++)
>         {
>             if (i != 0)
>                 if (Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
>                     return true;
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

instead write it like this

```
    private bool BonusPoints()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Letters.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i != 0 && Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Your nested if statements without bracing is just asking for trouble, and you don't need to nest these 2 if statements anyway, they can be merged into one conditional statement, like I did there.

**Edit**: Also stealing from the new Code Review user

You should just start from 1 in your for loop and get rid of that extra iteration and the condition in your if statement.  Good Catch [@guntanis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/77015/guntanis)

You would end up with this

```
    private bool BonusPoints()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.Letters.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

This:

> ```
>     private int GetMultiplier()
>     {
>         if (this.Length <= 4)
>             return 1;
>         else if (this.Length <= 6)
>             return 2;
>         else if (this.Length <= 9)
>             return 3;
>         else
>             return 4;
>     }
> ```

Would look better if you just incremented the numbers by 1 and used a less than instead of a less than or equal to.

```
    private int GetMultiplier()
    {
        if (this.Length < 5)
            return 1;
        else if (this.Length < 7)
            return 2;
        else if (this.Length < 10)
            return 3;
        else
            return 4;
    }
```

or even like reversed it like this,

```
    private int GetMultiplier()
    {
        if (this.Length > 9)
            return 4;
        else if (this.Length > 6)
            return 3;
        else if (this.Length > 4)
            return 2;
        else
            return 1;
    }
```

One less character per condition either way.  This doesn't really matter, it just depends on how you want the code interpreted by Humans I guess

---

This bit of code is missing something

> ```
>     private int GetLetterPoints()
>     {
>         int score = 0;
>         foreach (char letter in this.Letters)
>         {
>             switch (letter)
>             {
>                 case 'a':
>                 case 'e':
>                 case 'o':
>                 case 's':
>                     score += 1;
>                     break;
>                 case 'c':
>                 case 'f':
>                 case 'g':
>                 case 'i':
>                 case 'l':
>                 case 'r':
>                 case 't':
>                 case 'u':
>                     score += 2;
>                     break;
>                 case 'd':
>                 case 'h':
>                 case 'k':
>                 case 'm':
>                 case 'n':
>                     score += 3;
>                     break;
>                 case 'j':
>                 case 'p':
>                 case 'w':
>                 case 'y':
>                     score += 5;
>                     break;
>                 case 'q':
>                     score += 7;
>                     break;
>                 case 'v':
>                 case 'z':
>                     score += 8;
>                     break;
>             }
>         }
>         return score;
>     }
> ```

It is missing 2 whole letters,

1. X
2. B

You should also have a Default case

Comment: I actually think the `<=` is clearer, especially if the rules are written something like ("Words up to x characters long have a y multiplier."). `<` would be clearer if the rules said "Words shorter than x", though I think the former is more common.

Comment: Recommending `for (int i = 0; i < this.Letters.Count(); i++)` is using the extensions from Linq which will enumerate the entire collection every time the for loop moves to the next item. The correct usage here would be to use the `.Length` indexer from the `Letters` array: `for (int i = 0; i < this.Letters.Length; i++)` Here's an example demonstrating the difference: https://dotnetfiddle.net/izP5sD

Answer (score 13):

There are lots of good points in the answers so far and I'll try not to repeat them. Here are a few additional thoughts on how I would have preferred to see this code written.

---

**What concept does the `Word` class represent?**  I expect the principle concern of a class called `Word` to be things having to do with words, but this class seems primarily concerned with computing scrabble scores.  But that's not the big problem. The big problem is...

---

**Why is this a class at all**?  Why not simply make a method that takes a string and returns a score?  Sure, maybe make that method a static method of a class called `ScrabbleRules` or some such thing, but the design as it stands seems like the object-orientedness was just thrown in for no good reason. OOP is not an end in itself, it's a means to an end.

---

```
throw new Exception("Enter only one word");
```

Wait a minute, that exception is being thrown by the `Word` class. **How does that class know that a word was entered on the console?** Remember, the job of this class is to compute scores; you've done a good job here of separating the concern of user interfaces from the concern of scrabble policy, and then the exception message goes and conflates them again.

---

This is a minor and subtle point, but worth making.  **Don't mutate things that you don't need to mutate.** Consider this method body:

```
    {
        int CurrentScore = 0;
        CurrentScore += GetLetterPoints();
        if (BonusPoints()) 
          CurrentScore += 3;
        CurrentScore *= GetMultiplier();
        return CurrentScore;
    }
```

`CurrentScore` is mutated four times. It need not be mutated any times:

```
    {
        int letterPoints = GetLetterPoints();
        int bonusPoints = GetBonusPoints();
        int multiplier = GetMultiplier();
        return (letterPoints + bonusPoints) * multiplier;
    }
```

You tell me: which version makes it *abundantly clear* that the rule of the game is "total points is the sum of the letter and bonus points, all multiplied by the score multiplier", yours or mine?

---

Another minor point: in the point above, notice how in your code, `GetLetterPoints` and `GetMultiplier` are made responsible for computing a value, but this code is responsible for computing the bonus?  Why is there one method that is smart enough to figure out that there is a bonus, and then requires another method to know that the bonus value should be three?  My version is cleaner: the helper methods all compute values.

---

Here we have a method that does too much:

```
    private int GetLetterPoints()
    {
        int score = 0;
        foreach (char letter in this.Letters)
        {
            switch (letter)
            {
                case 'a':
                   score += ...
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
```

This would be much cleaner if it were simply

```
    private int GetLetterPoints()
    {
        int score = 0;
        foreach (char letter in this.Letters)
            score += LetterScore(letter);
        return score;
    }
```

Or for that matter

```
    private int GetLetterPoints()
    {
        var query = from letter in Letters select LetterScore(letter);
        return query.Sum();
    }
```

---

Speaking of that `switch` statement: you might replace it with a table:

```
static Dictionary<char, int> LetterScores = new Dictionary<char, int>()
{
    { 'a', 1 },
    { 'b', 3 }, 
    ...
};
```

And now the method above becomes

```
    private int GetLetterPoints()
    {
        var query = from letter in Letters select LetterScores[letter];
        return query.Sum();
    }
```

---

Finally, you asked about comments. I found your code easy to read and understand without any comments. If you have to write a comment to point out a tricky bit of code, better to rewrite it so that it doesn't need the comment.  I recommend that comments be used mostly to explain *why* a piece of code was written the way it was written, not *what the code does*.

The comments I would want to see in your code would be things like why `ToLower` is used instead of `ToLowerInvariant`, or for that matter, why it is being lowered at all. Or comments describing which part of the rules of the game are the responsibility of which parts of the code, if that is anywhere unclear.

Comment: would you recommend adding XML-comments (/// ...) before the method declarations? Because that is something I'd do, especially if I had to hand it in.

Comment: @Armin: That's a good point. XML doc comments first, as you note, demonstrate that you understand the concept. Second, they are useful to more than just people reading the code, as they also show up in IntelliSense.

Comment: **"which version makes it abundantly clear..."** couldn't agree more with you Eric, great answer.  To write code is to write self-documenting code.  it is utterly trivial to achieve the task at hand. The whole, total, complete concept of "engineering" here is to write it in such a way that it is as clear as sunlight, beyond clear, knock-you-on-the-head clear.  Good one.

Comment: We would love to have your wealth of Knowledge to draw from, just a chat ping away, please consider joining us in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) from time to time

Answer (score 12):

Some function could be more short.

In this function the else between the ifs statements is redundant.

```
        private int GetMultiplier()
        {
            if (this.Length <= 4)
                return 1;
            else if (this.Length <= 6)
                return 2;
            else if (this.Length <= 9)
                return 3;
            else
                return 4;
        }
```

you could transform it to this shorter version:

```
        private static int GetMultiplier()
        {
            int[] multi = { 4, 6, 9 }; // this could be a static member.
            int i = 0;
            while (i<multi.Length && Length > multi[i++]) ;

            return i;
        }
```

Also the branch inside the loop could be avoided just by starting at 1

```
        private bool BonusPoints()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < this.Letters.Count(); i++)
            {

                //if (i != 0)
                    if (Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
                        return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

You could also improve GetLetterPoints long switch cases are ugly and bad for mantainability among other things.

Comment: totally got thrown by the double nest and missed the obvious of starting from 1 instead of 0.  good catch

Comment: The shorter version of the GetMultiplier seems harder to read, would you still suggest it?

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder: I agree with you; I think your version of the code is easier to understand. If there were a thousand ranges then yes, the table-driven technique is superior, but for fewer than ten, I don't see a compelling benefit. I do however agree with MAG's points about the switch and the loop.

Comment: Yes the main benefit of my version of GetMuliplier would be having all the multipliers at the top of the class as a static member so it would be easier to scale and modify, but in this particular case you guys may be rigth and readability would be preferable.

Answer (score 12):

> ```
>             try
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a word:");
>
>             Word NewScrabbleWord = new Word(Console.ReadLine());
>
>
>             Console.WriteLine("Your score for this word is: {0}\n", NewScrabbleWord.Score);
>
>         }
>         catch (Exception all)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(all.Message + "\n");
>         }
> ```

Your indentation gets off there, and remains off to the rest of the file.  Initially, I thought you were missing a brace. Keep your indentation accurate and consistent to help with readability.

---

> ```
> Word NewScrabbleWord = new Word(Console.ReadLine());
> ```

You can use `var` there - after all, you just say `new Word()` in the assignment.

---

`if`s without braces are ugly.  As mentioned in another answer, this is bad:

> ```
> if (i != 0)
>     if (Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
>         return true;
> ```

It wouldn't be bad in the event you had something like this:

```
if (i != 0)
    if (Letters[i - 1] == Letters[i])
        certain statements here
else
    // other statements here
```

Where the `else` must execute if `i = 0`, regardless of the inner `if`. Use your braces.

---

Exceptions here?

> ```
> if (Letters.Any())
>     return Letters.Count();
> else
>     throw new Exception("You never entered anything");
> ```

I would just return `0`.  After all, nothing is the same as `0`, right?  In fact, you could probably just `return Letters.Count()`, unless `Letters` hasn't been initialized yet, in which case it would throw a `NullReferenceException()`.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use var instead of word, could you elaborate?

Comment: Some people use `var`, and others don't.  It isn't really needed when you put ` = new Word()` right after the declaration, because you tell yourself what it is.  Either always use it when possible, or never use it - just stay consistent.

Answer (score 7):

## Use of exceptions

I'll avoid getting into the "exceptions as flow control" arguments here. However, you can still improve on how you use exceptions.

#### Don't throw `Exception`. [[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]

You should always create (or use existing) subclasses.

For example:

```
throw new Exception("Enter only one word");
```

Should be:

```
throw new TooManyWordsException();
```

Alternatively:

```
// should be in the constructor
throw new ArgumentException("Input should only contain a single word.", "Word");
```

Corollary: don't catch `Exception` for flow control. The only place you should ever catch `Exception` is for last-chance logging before exiting the program, because a catch-all handler can never know which specific exception happened or how to deal with it.

#### Validate input early. Don't create an object with invalid state.

You currently only throw exceptions when `Letters` or `Length` are accessed (or one of the *many* methods that depend on them!). Ideally, you'd do the validation in the constructor (or wherever else you take input).

```
public Word(string input)
{
    if (input.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Input must not be empty.", "input");
    }

    if (input.Contains(" "))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Input should only contain a single word.", "input");
    }

    this.Value = input;
}
```

If you do this, you won't need a `try..catch` around every invocation of a potentially-dangerous method.

Notice I also avoid naming the parameter `Word`, which would become confusing (does `Word` refer to the class/type or the variable?). Ideally, the `Value` field would also have a better name (though I can't think of one right now), since `Value` is rather nondescriptive.

## Naming conventions

There's no *official* naming convention for variable identifiers in C#. However, the most commonly used ([[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774294/c-sharp-variable-naming)], [[3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209532/name-convention-for-variables-in-c)]) conventions typically distinguish local variables by starting with lowercase (or an underscore).

To be clear: what you're doing isn't *wrong*, per se, but it is a little bit odd compared to the majority of C# code.

For example:

```
int CurrentScore = 0;
```

Should be:

```
int currentScore = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. You mention validating in the constructor and robH seems to have put it in the program main, which would be better of the two?

Comment: @LiverpoolCoder This goes back to the "exceptions as flow control" argument. Basically, if you *expect* to hit the exception condition often, then you should check the conditions before calling the method (or creating the object, etc.). Exceptions should only be thrown rarely. But if you were designing a reusable class you'd want to *also* check in the constructor, because you can't guarantee the caller has already checked. In your particular case, you'll find some people prefer one way and some prefer the other. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why - to sum up, the constructor should always validate the arguments but best practice would also have the caller perform validation where possible, and maybe even have a `TryParseWord` or similar that returns a bool indicating success and an `out` param with the `Word`. But, again, people make arguments for both sides: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107723/arguments-for-or-against-using-try-catch-as-logical-operators

Answer (score 6):

The `BonusPoints` method can be rewritten using LINQ:

```
private bool BonusPoints()
{
    return Letters.Zip(Letters.Skip(1), (x, y) => x == y).Any(x => x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of good points in the other answers but I just want to add one thing.

**Don't throw exceptions from property getters**

It's in the official MS Guidelines for [Property Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx)

> If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method. Notice that this rule does not apply to indexers, where we do expect exceptions as a result of validating the arguments.

So this:

```
public Word(string Word)
{
   this.Value = Word;
}

public char[] Letters
{
    get
    {
        if (!Value.Contains(" "))
            return Regex.Replace(Value.ToLower(), "[^a-z]+", "").ToArray();
        else
            throw new Exception("Enter only one word");
    }
}
```

Should be rewritten so that you validate the `Word` in the constructor. Or better yet, avoid the exception altogether:

```
string userInput = " ";
while (userInput.Contains(" "))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word to score...");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine(); 
}
var word = new Word(userInput);
```

Comment: Very good point